# CALayer rotation appears to 'lift' it's child above the surface

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation

Here is the iPad Simulator with four nested `UIView`s, drawing a custom background, and an inner `UILabel`.  I am rotating the top `UIView`'s CALayer, by getting it's layer and setting `transform` with a rotateY `CATransform3D`, animated on a separate thread (but the changes to `transform` are being sent on the main thread, naturally):

[image: Oh deary me]

Note- this animation does not loop correctly, hence it appears to bounce.

The layers *do* animate as a whole, but curiously, the first child and it's descendants appear to be floating above the `UIView` with the transform applied!

The `UIView`s themselves are children in another `UIView`, which has a red background.  There are no other transformations being applied anywhere else.

The positions for each UIView were set using `setFrame` initially at the start.

What is causing this strange behaviour, and how can I ensure the child `UIView`s transform with their parent, giving a flat appearance to the surface as a whole?

Comment: Layers have `zPosition` property. It's zero by default, but maybe something went wrong. You can try to set it manually. It's the only thing I can think of..

Comment: Nope, manually forcing the `zPosition` of the child to 0 (or any other value) has no discernable effect, and logging the value claims it is initially zero.  That said, *should* setting `zPosition` to say, 100, be obviously doing something? If so that could be a clue.

Comment: It does nothing, sorry for false hope ;) I just tried a lot of things but couldn't get that cool effect of yours, so I don't know how did you get it. Btw I used a regular  `CABasicAnimation`, maybe you can use it in your code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. Perhaps unsurprisingly I was doing something silly, but since I'd not used CALayer transforms before, I didn't know if things were acting up.  I had overridden `layoutSubviews` on the UIViews I was creating, and the act of rotating the CALayer was triggering this call and then pushing the child components frame around, due to a bug.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that CALayers don't actually do 3D perspective by default. In order to do that you need to make a minor change to the layer's transform (which is of type CATransform3D)

You want to change the .m34 field of the transform to a small negative value. Try -1/200 to -1/500 as a starting range. If I remember correctly it should be the negative of 1 over the image height/width.

Change the .m34 property of the layer that you want to appear to "come off the page" and rotate in 3D. When you do that the Z setting of the layer does matter, and will both make closer layers bigger and also make layers that are further away disappear behind other things.

I suggest you do a Google search on "CATransform3D m34" for more information. There is a fair amount of information on the net about it.

Comment: I don't want 3D perspective at the moment, and I understand how to set up projection matrices. I am not sure you have read my question.